# I need help with this dent classification rule

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, fixed-wing, damage

I'm an Aerospace Engineer from Chile, and I have the following reference issue:
Supposedly there's a damage rule related to dents on aircraft skin that says

> *If the distance between two dents is lower than twice of the biggest
> diameter of the greater dent, they could be considered as one dent*

, but I can't find the norm that references it.
Could anyone help me to figure it out?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I can't find anything in FAA reference documents that talks about dent spacing...